# Checking if the quantity is low in stock in C#

Tags: c#, database, stock

I was trying to display the message "Low in Stock" if the quantity ordered is greater than stock by reducing the quantity in stock although it just displays "Ordered Successfuly" and the quantity reduces to a negative

[image]

The code below is what i tried but it just displays ordered successful even if the ordered quantity more than what is in stock

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE Product SET ProdQty-=" + TextBox_qtys.Text + "  WHERE ProdId=" + TextBox_id.Text + "";

if (updateQuery==null )
{
    SqlCommand commands = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, dBCon.GetCon());
    dBCon.OpenCon();
    commands.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Low in Stock ", "Low Stock", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    dBCon.CloseCon();
    getTable();
    clear();
}
else 
{
    SqlCommand commands = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, dBCon.GetCon());
    dBCon.OpenCon();
    commands.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Order Added Successfully", "Update Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    dBCon.CloseCon();
    getTable();
    clear();
}
```

Comment: You're setting `updateQuery` to the result of a string concatenation. How would that ever be null? It's unclear how you expect that condition to detect low stock, given that at that point you haven't communicated with the database at all... (Aside from anything else, you should look into SQL Injection Attacks and start parameterizing your query, but that's slightly separate.)

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your `updateQuery` variable will never be null because you're setting it by yourself before. So the low in stock part will never be executet.

You need to query the datebase first to get the current quantity.

Something like this:

```cs
string query = "SELECT ProdQty FROM Product WHERE ProdID=@id";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_id.Text));
var qty = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

then you can check the quantity stored in the database against your order.
To decide either to process or discard it with an message.

```cs
if (qty < Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_qtys.Text)) {
// MSG BOX LOW Stock
} else {
// Update query to store order
}
```

Take a look at the parameterized query already mentioned in the comments.
Also check the datatypes I asume here the quantity is an integer.